# What is stored in the shift amount field of R type instructions

Tags: mips, mips32

An R-type instruction has the format: **opcode rs rt rd shamt func**.

For example, I have an R-type instruction `sll $s0,$so,2`, what is stored in shamt (shift amount) field of the above format?

Comment: This is something you can easily find out for yourself: put that instruction in an assembly file and load it into a MIPS simulator (e.g. QtSPIM or MARS), then look at the generated machine code. If you don't want to install anything you could translate the instruction into the machine code you _think_ it corresponds to and use [an online disassembler](https://www.onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/) to verify.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting online disassembler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shamt stands for shift amount which will contain the number by which you want you shift, in this case 2, so the shamt will be 2 in binary: `00010`